# SCoP, Iteration Domain in Polyhedral Optimization and use of Presburger arithmetic

Tags: optimization, sets, notation, loops, iteration

**Context:**

While exploring the fundamentals of polyhedral optimization and **attempting to explore a connection from the input Static Control Part (SCoP) to the iteration domain from birds eye view**, I am confused about whether I am making the correct connections or not.

**Explored connection map:**

[image]

**Example case:**

Let's see a code snippet;

```
# SCOP
for i in range(1, 9): # 1 and 9 are loop bounds
    for j in range(i+1, 10): # i+1 and 9 are loop bounds
#         statement S

Triangle = isl.BasicSet("{S[i,j] : 0 < i < j <= 9}") 
plot_set_points(Triangle,color='blue')
```

**Output**

[image]

Consider the above nested loop, which exhibits Static Control Part (SCOP) characteristics, the iteration vectors we get are as follows:

`{(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),(1, 7),(1, 8),(1, 9),(2, 3),(2, 4),(2, 5),(2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 8),(2, 9),(3, 4),(3, 5),(3, 6),(3, 7),(3, 8),(3, 9),(4, 5),(4, 6),(4, 7),(4, 8),(4, 9),(5, 6),(5, 7),(5, 8),(5, 9),(6, 7),(6, 8),(6, 9),(7, 8),(7, 9),(8, 9)}`.

These vectors correspond to the values of the i and j variables within the loop bounds.

And the vectors satisfy loop-bound conditions; `1<= i < 9 and i+1 <= j < 10`

From loop bound condition we derive the Presburger formula; `i >= 1 ∧ i < 9 ∧ j > i ∧ j <= 9`

Thus, we can say the iteration vectors also satisfy the Presburger formula. As a result, this set of iteration vectors can be called a Presburger Set.

The Presburger formula and set can be expressed in set builder notation as; `{S[i,j] : 0 < i < j <= 9}`

This notation can be passed as an argument to `isl.BasicSet`, and we can visualize the iter domain derived from the set (refer to the output diagram above).

**So my doubts are…**

Q1. Are the connections that I have explored on the right track?

Q2. If the answer to Q1 is NO, what am I missing?

**N.B.**: I am aware that my explorations so far may be somewhat abstract, but I would greatly appreciate insights into whether I am misunderstanding anything.

Thank you

Comment: I have no clue about polyhedral optimization, but it might help others to answer if you can hint where you are having your doubts.

Comment: I can't understand what your question is.  On this site, we expect you to articulate a single, specific question.  Open-ended questions of the form "here are a bunch of thoughts, am I on the right track?" or "here is a long list of my impressions, what am I missing?" are normally not suitable here.  Please pick one specific technical question you have about this topic area.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Also, we hope that questions will be formulated in a way that they'll be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the answer,  I am at the initial stage of my study for polyhedral optimization. And I am trying to connect things with less knowledge of it. So, I decided to share the findings or the connections with others, if anyone could point out to me that the way I am connecting is right or wrong. But, if my post is completely irrelevant to this site then I think I would better delete it.

Comment: It can be relevant if you can rewrite your question to fit the rules, for example what doubts you are having, what haven't you connected, what knowledge you are lacking. It doesn't matter how advanced the topic is, how well formatted the content is, there needs to be a clear question to be answered. When you've edited your question with enough clarity and still receive no answer, I would suggest trying asking in Theoretical CS SE, as searching for "polyhedral" in CS SE only yields 9 results, while there are 39 results in Theoretical CS SE.

Comment: As Kenneth Kho explains, that doesn't fit the purpose of this site.  Our goal is to build a library of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the form of questions and answers.  To make it fit the site format, we need you to articulate a specific, narrowly focused technical question, and hopefully one that someone else might have in the future.  So if there is a single aspect of the subject that you are unsure about, then you could ask a question about that specific item you are unclear on.  But asking us to check over an essay to see whether it is correct doesn't fit our format.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the answer. I will try to question specifically next time. Bounty questions might not be able to delete I guess. May be after expiration